# How to instantiate an object using LambdaMetaFactory?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, invokedynamic, lambda-metafactory

I have an interface Action:

```
package action;

public interface Action {
    public String act();
}
```

Class SimpleAction:

```
package action;

public class SimpleAction implements Action {

    String action;
    public SimpleAction() {}

    public SimpleAction(String x) {
        this.action = x;
    }

    @Override
    public String act() {
        return "Act method from -" + this.action;
    }
}
```

Class ComplexAction:

```
    package action;

    public class ComplexAction implements Action{

        String action;
        public ComplexAction() {}
        public ComplexAction(String x) {
            this.action = x;
        }
        @Override
        public String act() {
            return "Act method from -" + this.action;
        }
    }
```

I want to create a function which takes the name of class and returns an object of that class.
This is what I have so far in my function -

```
 

    public static Action resultOfActMethod(String objclass){   
        Class clazz = Class.forName(objclass);
        MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
        MethodHandle mh = lookup.findConstructor(clazz,MethodType.methodType(void.class, String.class));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
public static Action resultOfActMethod(String objclass){    
    Class clazz = Class.forName(objclass);
    MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
    MethodHandle mh = lookup.findConstructor(clazz, MethodType.methodType(void.class, String.class));
    Function<String, Action> constructor = (Function<String, Action>)LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup, "apply",MethodType.methodType(Function.class),
                        mh.type().generic(), mh, mh.type()).getTarget().invokeExact();
    Action action = constructor.apply(objclass);
    return action;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do just this, it will give you an object, using the constructor with no arguments:

```
public static Object resultOfActMethod(String objclass) 
    throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {
  Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(objclass);
  return clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
}
```

But if possible in your application, you should make a function which takes a class instead like this:

```
public static <C> C resultOfActMethod(Class<C> clazz) 
    throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {
  return clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
}
```

This is typesafe. You can use a specific return type. This will avoid a type cast at the caller's side.

Comment: Referring the Java doc I don't think its wise to use this approach. The javadoc specifically says "Use of this method effectively bypasses the compile-time exception checking that would otherwise be performed by the compiler. The Constructor.newInstance method avoids this problem by wrapping any exception thrown by the constructor in a (checked) InvocationTargetException."

Comment: Thanks to Google, StackOverflow and bit of research I was able to solve it. I posted my answer below.

Comment: The poster of this question specifically asked for an answer related to `LambdaMetafactory`, a standard reflection example shouldn't be given.