# How to invoke default constructor using LambdaMetafactory

Tags: java-8, lambda-metafactory

In the link:
[How to instantiate an object using LambdaMetaFactory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53675777/how-to-instantiate-an-object-using-lambdametafactory) it is mentioned how to instantiate a one-arg contrcutor using LambdaMetafactory.

I am trying to do the same for default-constructor but is failing with the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method com/test/Main$$Lambda$1.apply(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; is abstract
at com.test.Main$$Lambda$1/186370029.apply(Unknown Source)
at com.test.Main.test2(Main.java:29)
at com.test.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

Code I am trying to run:

```
import java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodType;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    long t2= System.nanoTime();
    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
      test2(TestClass.class.getName());
    }
    long t3= System.nanoTime();

    System.out.println((t3-t2)*1e-9);
  }

  private static TestClass test2(String objclass)
      throws Throwable {
    Class clazz = Class.forName(objclass);
    MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
    MethodHandle mh = lookup.findConstructor(clazz, MethodType.methodType(void.class));
    Function<String, TestClass> constructor = (Function<String, TestClass>) LambdaMetafactory
        .metafactory(lookup, "apply",MethodType.methodType(Function.class),
            mh.type().generic(), mh, mh.type()).getTarget().invokeExact();
    TestClass testClass = constructor.apply(objclass);
    return testClass;
  }

}
```

TestClass

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestClass {

  public Map<String, String> getContextMap() {
    return Collections.emptyMap();
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong in order to invoke the default constructor using LambdaMetafactory?

Comment: There’s not much sense in converting the `Class` to a name `String` and back to the `Class`. Further, you should separate the construction of the function instance from using the instance, as no real life code would repeatedly construct the same function. Not even Reflection does that when you use, e.g. `TestClass.class.getConstructor().newInstance()`…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your default constructor takes no parameter. Change `Function` to `Supplier`:

```
private static TestClass test2(String objclass)
        throws Throwable {
    Class clazz = Class.forName(objclass);
    MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
    MethodHandle mh = lookup.findConstructor(clazz, MethodType.methodType(void.class));
    Supplier<TestClass> constructor = (Supplier<TestClass>) LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(
            lookup, "get", MethodType.methodType(Supplier.class), mh.type().generic(), mh, mh.type()
    ).getTarget().invokeExact();
    TestClass testClass = constructor.get();
    return testClass;
}
```